# React - State items flickering when data is the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I allow users to search for other users within my component using a `query` state variable to track this. Whenever this query changes, after a timeout, the query is performed and the new users are mapped on screen. Here is the code for this:

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState("")
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
const [noResultsFound, setNoResultsFound] = useState(false)


useEffect(() => {
    if (query === "" || !query) return

    let timer = setTimeout(async () => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        const res = await axiosPrivate.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/users/get_users/${query}`, { headers: { "x-auth-token": token } })
        if (res?.data?.length === 0) {
            setUsers([])
            setNoResultsFound(true)
        } else {
            setUsers(res.data)
            setNoResultsFound(false)
            console.log(users)
        }

        setIsLoading(false)
    }, 500)

    return () => {
        clearTimeout(timer)
    }
}, [query])
```

Then I map the users array on the screen if they are available, otherwise I display a loading indicator. If no results were found for the query, then some text indicating this is displayed instead.

```
            {isLoading && (
                <Spinner
                    noDelay={true}
                    withStyles={false}
                />
            )}

            {!isLoading && noResultsFound === false && users.length > 0 && (
                <>
                    {users.map((user) => (
                        <p key={uuidv4()}{ user.username}</p>
                    ))}
                </>
            )}

            {!isLoading && noResultsFound === true && users.length === 0 && <p>No users</p>}
```

The problem I have is that if the `query` changes, and the exact same results are returned from the `API`, a flicker occurs for each of the `users` list items. I have ensured all my `keys` for the mapped items are unique. How can I ensure that if the **exact** same results are returned from the API, then don't re-render the list items to avoid the flicker on screen. If this is not a solution, is there any potential methods I could use in order to avoid this flickering? Thanks.

Comment: be careful with `res?.data?.length === 0`. when `res={}` or `res={data: null}` you will get `undefined === 0` which is **false** and runs the `else` branch of your code.

Comment: consider changing the entire `if..else` to `setUsers(res?.data ?? [])` and replace any instance of `noResultsFound` with `users.length == 0`.

Comment: read [Fetching Data](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#fetching-data) from the React Docs. you need to prevent `setState` functions being called in `.then(...)` if the component has unmounted

Comment: obviously that's a lot to do for one request on one component, that's why you should write a custom hook that encapsulates all of this. or use a community-supported library.

Comment: @Mulan As adam mentioned below, state is not the issue I believe, it's the loading variable which is set to true each API call, meaning even if the results are the same, the flicker occurs. Removing the `isLoading` from the condition to render the users confirmed this

Comment: sorry i wasn't more clear, i'm not attempting to answer your question. i'm pointing out other problems in your code you didn't ask about.

Comment: This is very minor compared to the other issues that people have already pointed out, but FYI, `query === "" || !query` is redundant, because the empty string is falsy; you can just write `!query`.

Comment: other problems exist: in your rendering logic, what if `isLoading=false` and `noResultsFound=false` and `users=[]`? you never *intend* for that to happen, but nothing prevents it. this is additional support for removing `noResultsFound` and deriving it directly from `users` state itself. to fix your rendering, you should be using exclusive or branching so **one and only one** possible state can render. for example `if (isLoading) return "loading"; else if (users == null) return "do a search"; else if (users.length == 0) return "no results found"; else return <Users users={users} />`

Comment: @Mulan: I actually don't think it's possible to get `noResultsFound=false` and `users=[]`, because the only code-path that could set `noResultsFound=false` also sets `users` to something (almost anything) other than `[]`. But your overall point is sound.

Answer (score 1):

```
            {!isLoading && noResultsFound === false && users.length > 0 && (
                <>
                    {users.map((user) => (
                        <p key={uuidv4()}>{user.username}</p>
                    ))}
                </>
            )}
```

You only render the list of users if `isLoading` is false. So that means that every time you kick off an API request, the list is hidden until the API request completes. You can just remove `!isLoading` from this conditional, but I suspect you might run into other UX issues if you do that.

I know you shouldn't add libraries for such a simple thing, but I suggest to use `tanstack/query` or `useSWR` - it drastically simplifies this type of code and the solutions to all your UX problems are answered somewhere in their documentation.

PS: Your keys make your list less performant - they change every time the list is rendered - you should use something like this

```
                    {users.map((user) => (
                        <p key={user.id}>{user.username}</p>
                    ))}
```

Comment: I changed my keys to something unique and constant i.e `user.id` however to solve the other issue, is there a way I could avoid updating state if the results are exactly the same as the previous ones?

Comment: @Herbadams - updating the users state is not the issue - the issue is that you are temporarily hiding your list with your conditional check of `isLoading`. It looks like it's "flickering", but it's not "flickering" - it's being hidden (when `isLoading` is true) and then shown again (after `isLoading` is set to false).

Comment: +1 for correctly explaining the problem, but I don't think the library suggestion is a good one. The OP is clearly struggling a bit with both JavaScript and React; adding yet another set of things for him/her to imperfectly understand will just make it harder for him/her to catch up.

Comment: @AdamJenkins Without adding another library, is there a potential method I could use in order to accomplish this with plain javascript and react?

Comment: @ruakh What method do you suggest?

Comment: @Herbadams - I said it in my answer - remove `!isLoading` from the conditional. This may introduce UX problems for you, or it may not, but it will definitely stop the "flickering". Either way, you have a UX problem now, not a code problem, the code is fine.

Comment: @ruakh And by the way you dont know me or my skill level, so I suggest you stop making assumptions relating to my competence

Comment: @Herbadams: I don't know you, but I've read your code, your question, and your comments here. I'm not judging you as a person, a developer in general, etc.; but yes, I see that you're struggling to write JavaScript/React code that you understand. There's no shame in that — we all have to start at zero and learn from there.

Comment: @ruakh I understand, however you cannot judge a persons ability based on a snippet of code and "comments" on a post. This is a very old snippet of code from an old project, therefore I realise now it's not the best, however changing it would be pointless as it would not fix the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are generating a new key on the fly for every render.

```
<p key={uuidv4()}>{ user.username}</p>
```

You need to understand how `key`s work under the hood in React. React uses the `key` prop to uniquely identify the component. When the `key` changes, React will assume that it is a new component.

In this case, React will encounter a paragraph tag with a new `key` on every render. This will make the virtual DOM render a new component.

It is a bad practice to generate a `key` in this manner. Not providing a `key` is better than providing a `key` that is not in the control of the user.

**Solution**

Every `user` will have a unique property associated with it. Ideally it would be `user.id`. In this case, the username will be unique as well. This will server as a better candidate for a `key`.

```
<p key={user.username}>{ user.username}</p>
```

Now, React can re-use the previously rendered components by matching the keys.

Comment: After updating this, the flickering is still occuring

Comment: Everything in this answer is right, except the part where it says that this is "the problem". It's not. The incorrect keys will cause unnecessary re-rendering, but the unnecessary re-rendering won't cause flickering in this case, because React will remove the old components and add the new ones in a single atomic operation, and the components have no mount/unmount logic. It's just a performance issue. (Well, unless the OP is using weird CSS transitions. But there's no need to posit that, when the other answer already gives the real explanation.)

Answer (score -1):

```html
import { useMemo } from 'react';

// ...

const MemoizedUsers = useMemo(() => users, [users]);

return (
  <>
    {isLoading && (
      <Spinner
        noDelay={true}
        withStyles={false}
      />
    )}

    {!isLoading && noResultsFound === false && MemoizedUsers.length > 0 && (
      <>
        {MemoizedUsers.map((user) => (
          <p key={uuidv4()}>{user.username}</p>
        ))}
      </>
    )}

    {!isLoading && noResultsFound === true && MemoizedUsers.length === 0 && <p>No users</p>}
  </>
);
```

In this modified code, the MemoizedUsers variable is a memoized version of the users array. It will only change if the reference of the users array changes. This way, when the exact same results are returned from the API, and the users array reference remains the same, it won't trigger unnecessary re-renders and flickering.

Comment: This makes no sense; `const MemoizedUsers = useMemo(() => users, [users]);` is just a convoluted way of writing `const MemoizedUsers = users;`.